# La signifo de forlaso de la artikolo

Tags: article

En la angla, laŭ mia kompreno estas tri elektoj por artikoloj:

- La difina artikolo: *the man who lives around the corner*
- La nedifina artikolo: *a dog*
- Forlaso de artikolo: *human rights*

En Esperanto estas nur unu artikolo, do oni povas nur aldoni aŭ ne aldoni ĝin. Se mi ĝuste komprenas forlaso de la artikolo similas al la nedifina artikolo en la angla.

Ankaŭ en la Franca estas du artikoloj, kaj ŝajnas ke oni ne forlasas la artikolon krom specialaj okazoj, do efektive estas elekto nur inter difina kaj nedifina kiel en Esperanto. Tamen la uzo de la du eblecoj ne ŝajne estas sama inter Esperanto kaj la franca. Vidu ekzemple ĉi tiujn tri tradukojn de la sama frazo el [la deklaracio de homaj rajtoj](http://www.ohchr.org/EN/UDHR/Pages/Language.aspx?LangID=1115):

- l'esclavage et la traite des esclaves sont interdits sous toutes leurs formes
- sklaveco kaj sklavkomerco estu malpermesitaj en ĉiuj siaj formoj
- slavery and the slave trade shall be prohibited in all their forms

Do la demando estas, kial oni ne diras “la sklaveco”? Ŝajnas ke oni parolas pri sklaveco kiel unu unika koncepto, do ĝi estas kvazaŭ difinita, do kial oni ne uzas la difinan artikolon? Mi havas la impreson ke kiam oni ne uzas artikolon en la angla, oni same ne uzas artikolon en Esperanto, sed mi ne vere komprenas la logikon.

Interese ankaŭ estas ke en la franca traduko de [la fundamento](http://www.akademio-de-esperanto.org/fundamento/gramatiko_franca.html) estas ĉi tiu frazo:

> L’emploi de l’article est le même qu’en français ou en allemand.

Tio ŝajnas ne ĝusta almenaŭ laŭ la supra ekzemplo.

Comment: Ankaŭ la hispana uzas _la_ en tiu frazo: _**la** esclavitud y **la** trata de esclavos están prohibidas en todas sus formas_.

Comment: Ĉu vi legis la ĉapitron de PMEG pri la artikolo? Verŝajne vi trovos la respondon tie: http://bertilow.com/pmeg/gramatiko/difiniloj/la/index.html

Answer (score 2):

En la rusa versio de la Fundamento, la citato diras ne nur pri la franca kaj la germana, sed ankaŭ pri "**aliaj** [lingvoj]":

> Примѣчаніе. Употребленіе члена такое же, какъ въ языкахъ нѣмецкомъ, французскомъ **и другихъ.**

Se oni konas la germanan kaj la francan, oni scias, ke iliaj sistemoj de la uzado de artikoloj ne estas tute samaj. Se oni ankaŭ inkluzivas "aliajn lingvojn" (ekz. la angla), oni havas la problemojn, kiujn vi priskribas. Sed, la citato ne estas plena. La dua parto diras (france i ruse):

> Mais les personnes auxquelles il présenterait quelque difficulté peuvent fort bien ne pas s’en servir.
>
> Лица, для которыхъ употребленіе члена представляетъ трудности, могутъ совершенно его не употреблять.

Do, (la) solvo ŝajnas esti, ke oni povas uzi (la) artikolojn laŭ (la) uzo de (la) propra lingvo, kaj eĉ ne uzi ilin.

Comment: Estas interese ke PMEG ŝajnas malentuziasma pri tiu lasta konsilo: “En la Fundamenta Gramatiko estas skribite, ke personoj, por kiuj la uzado de la artikolo prezentas malfacilaĵon, povas tute ĝin ne uzi. Tiu permeso validas nur por komencantoj.”

Comment: Bone, sed ĉu ekzistas pli helpemaj oficialaj konsiloj pri la uzado?

Comment: Mi nun vidas, ke PMEG tre akribe describas la uzadon de la artikolo. Eble mi trovos iam tempon, por legi ĉion :-p

Comment: @Neil Roberts: simile al la konsilo de PMEG estas ankaŭ dirite en la Fundamenta Ekzercaro (§27): _La personoj, kiuj ne komprenas la uzadon de la artikolo (ekzemple rusoj aŭ poloj, kiuj ne scias alian lingvon krom sia propra), povas en la unua tempo tute ne uzi la artikolon, ĉar ĝi estas oportuna sed ne necesa_. La tuta frazo estas konsilo (kaj permeso) nur por tiuj, kiuj ne komprenas la artikolon, kaj nur en la unua tempo. Alivorte, ĉiuj lernu iam la uzadon de la artikolo.

Answer (score 2):

Bone, la uzo de artikoloj malsamas en diversaj lingvoj (ekzemple, la anglan, la hispanan, la francan, ktp), kaj la reguloj de la diversaj lingvoj rilate al ĉi tiuj artikoloj estas subtile nuancataj kaj ekscentraj. Pro tio, la reguloj de Esperanto permesas ke ĉiuj uzu la artikolojn laŭ iliaj propraj lingvaj kutimoj, sekvante la uzadon, kiun ili sentas natura.

Comment: +1 Saluton! Mi havas la saman opinion pri tio, kiel vi. Kiam vi havos 15 punktojn da reputacio, mi ĝoje ricevos vian voĉdonon :-)